# where to access redux store from parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a dashboard component that is displaying a table component.  On the dashboard component, I am loading the redux store with an account information through an async await call in componentdidmount,  I would like to use the account information from that call to filter data from the child table component.  Where should I try to access the redux store from the child component?  Currently I have it in componentdidmount and the values are empty.  When I put in console.logs in both componentdidmount, it appears that the dashboard componentdidmount is called after the child componentdidmount.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: you can use componentDidUpdate in child to check if the prop changed and take an action

Comment: use reselect for data aggregation/manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access redux store in the componentWillReceiveProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   console.log(nextProps);
}
```

Since React 16.3+ static getDerivedStateFromProps is introduced which is a static method that return state
For more information visit [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)